# Date selection flashes when closing datepicker

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

When you select a date in this example ([jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3wGx/65/)) you can briefly see another date being selected before the date picker closes.

Can you prevent this "flashing" of the selected date when the date picker closes?

```
<input type="text" id="booking-from" name="booking-from" />
<input type="text" id="booking-to" name="booking-to" />
```

jQuery

```
$("#booking-from").datepicker({
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) { 
        $( "#booking-to" ).datepicker( "option", "minDate", selectedDate );
    }
});
$("#booking-to").datepicker({
    onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#booking-from" ).datepicker( "option", "maxDate",  selectedDate);
    }
});
```

Comment: Try adding `setTimeout` (Ugly hack)

Comment: It's flashing the date from the other datepicker. I suspect it has something to do with the custom CSS you have.

Comment: It is selecting the current day (14). Try to disable that :)

Comment: Removing the `background` style for `.ui-datepicker .ui-datepicker-calendar tbody td a.ui-state-active` gets rid of the flashing. I'm not sure why. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/h3wGx/64/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I had to make two changes to get it to work.

I had to change `onClose` to `onSelect` and also add a timeout when setting the `maxDate/minDate` (thanks to @Shaunak D)

Here's the solution: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h3wGx/66/)

```
$("#booking-from").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#booking-to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);
        }, 200);
    }
});
$("#booking-to").datepicker({
    onSelect: function (selectedDate) {
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#booking-from").datepicker("option", "maxDate", selectedDate);
        }, 200);
    }
});
```